# Horror story: man in cabin attacked by demon escaped from enchanted well

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I am trying to identify a horror story that I read about two years ago. I remember part of the story involving a man in a cabin with a horse being attacked by a demon that had been sealed in a well and covered with rocks with some type of glyphs or script on them. Presumably these rocks were enchanted to keep the demon trapped. This may have been from a Stephen King collection or an anthology presented by Stephen King.

Comment: When did you read this? In English? Do you remember an approximate length of the story?

Comment: Is this on topic for science fiction & fantasy?

Answer (score 2):

Could it be [The Colour Out of Space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Colour_Out_of_Space) by H.P. Lovecraft?

The story involves a man in a cabin, an alien force that has infested the nearby well, and in the end his dead horse is found as remains.

The full story can be found [here](http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/cs.aspx).

Apologies for the stump answer. Unfortunately not able to provide more details at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I think the book you are looking for is [Ring by Koji Suzuki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28Suzuki_novel%29).

The entire sealed well portion matches, at least.

There was also a Japanese film and [an English film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ring_%282002_film%29) made by adapting the storyline. Have a look. Hope this helps.

Comment: This could be it. Could you add some more details (quotes in particular), so that people reading this know whether it is the right answer?

Comment: I don't think the horse would match, at the least, plus *The Ring* was a full-sized novel, not a story that would be in an anthology.